# Cómo eliminar redundancia en una tabla de tres atributos dos a dos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

mi pregunta era la siguiente:

Si tengo una tabla del estilo:

```
A | B | C
----------
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   2   1
1   2   2
2   1   1
2   1   2
```

Y quiero obtener una tabla resultante:

```
A | B | C
----------
1   1   1
1   2   1
2   1   2
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para conseguirlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

PD: Ya he probado agrupar por A, B y por B, C por separado y hacer un join después, pero obviamente, esto me dio la tabla original.

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues el código de lo que haz intentado y de preferencia que especifiques como llegas a ese resultado, ya que al menos en mi caso, no entiendo cuales reglas aplicas para agrupar de esa manera.

Comment: ¿Y cual sería el criterio para las tres filas finales?